# how to fix plot legend when using hsv to color code?

Tags: plot, legend, matlab-figure, hsv

I have my lines color coded using the hsv function, and they're all colored properly but for some reason in the legend, every other line (or stim #) is a black dashed line, rather than the actual color[color coded plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AUHH.png)

it seems like it's because of my line of code (below) right before the legend, as when I got rid of it (top subplot) the legend is normal. how can i fix the legend without removing this line of code??[code for plot above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMWJH.png)

xline(0, 'k--')